# ERB prints enitre string at end of each_line loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

This completely confused me for a while. I'm getting weird behaviour trying to loop through lines of text in erb, with the whole line of text being printed when the loop is complete.

```
<% "some\nmultiline\ntext".each_line do |line| %>
  <%= line %> <br />
<% end %>
```

Outputs:

```
some 
multiline 
text 
some multiline text
```

And so does:

```
<% "some\nmultiline\ntext".lines.each do |line| %>
  <%= line %> <br />
<% end %>
```

But the following works as I would expect it to:

```
<% "some\nmultiline\ntext".lines.to_a.each do |line| %>
  <%= line %> <br />
<% end %>
```

and prints:

```
some 
multiline 
text
```

I'm *definitely* not just putting in an `=` accidentally. What could be causing this strange behaviour?

I'm using Rails 3.0.10, Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure but `"some\nmultiline\ntext".lines` is `Enumerator` and `"some\nmultiline\ntext".lines.to_a` is `Enumerable` the big difference is that when you mix in `Enumerable` module to your class you have to define `each` method whose job it is to
yield items to a supplied code block, one at a time. Enumerators are a recent and significant  addition to Ruby. An enumerator is an object, not a method.  An enumerator isn’t a container object. It has no “natural” basis for an each operation, the way an array does (start at element 0; yield it; go to element 1; yield it; and so on). The each iteration logic of every enumerator has to be explicitly specified.

Comment: Chunks of text from The Well-Grounded Rubyist, Chapter 10.